# Using signalR to redirect user to 1 to 1 chat

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

So in my application I implemented to following sequence:

I have a NotificationsHub connected to all users. Then, through this hub, user1 sends a request to chat to user2. User2 accepts the request and is immediately redirected to the chat page, which belongs to another Hub, the ChatHub. When user2 finishes loading the page and creating the connection to the Hub, I use the same NotificationHub to send the connectionId of the chatHub to the user1 to redirect and connect him to the same chat.

My problem is this last part. I don't know if it has something to do with asyncronous calls, but when I try to send the user to the page it says it cannot send because the connection is not in the connected state.

Both users are redirected to the same page, the difference is in the role of the user connected:

```
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/notifications.js"></script>
<script>

    @if(User.IsInRole(Constantes.userRoleConsultor))
    {
        @:window.onload = function() {
            @:var chatId = document.cookie
            @:var chatDB = "@ViewData["ChatDb"]";
            @:var consultorId = "@ViewData["ConsultorId"]";
            @:var userId = "@ViewData["UserId"]";

            @:notificationsConnection.invoke("SendUserToChat", userId, chatId, chatDB).catch(function(err) {
              @:return console.log(err);
            @:});
        @:}
    }

    @if (User.IsInRole(Constantes.userRoleCustomer))
    {
        @:window.onload = function() {
            @:var chatId = "@ViewData["ChatId"]";
            @:var chatDB = "@ViewData["ChatDbId"]";
            @:var consultorId = "@ViewData["ConsultorId"]";
            @:var userId = "@ViewData["UserId"]";

            @:connectToChatHub(chatId);
        @:}
    
    }
</script>
```

So both users are loading my 2 hubs when they reach the page. And when the first user (he has the userRoleConsultor) finishes it, he sends a signal trough the notifications hub to "SendUserToChat", but here its when it says the notificationsConnection is not in a connected state.

I thought that by using window.onload() I would be able to wait for chat.js and notification.js to do all they need to do before proceding but looks like it doesent so I could use some ideas to fix my problem. Thank you!

Comment: It  would be nicer, if you could share your `NotificationHub` details. Because, first of all, we need to check if the connection has established  before invoking the method, you should ensure that the connection is in a connected state when you attempt to use it. So verify that both hubs are configured correctly, including connection establishment, event handling. Another important, thing is that, if the NotificationHub defined as asynchronous then in  client-side while invoking method you should handle the asynchronous operation as well.